# Объект FormData пустой, после добавления объектов

Tags: javascript, ajax

Мне необходимо отправлять файлы на сервер через ajax, вот мой код FormData, но проблема в том, что на после выполнения цикла, объект formData пустой и соответственно на сервер ничегно не приходитЮ в чём может быть проблема?

```
let products = []
const allFiles = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files
forms.forEach((item, index) => {
     let product = {}
     const files = new FormData()
     file_ids[index + 1].forEach((item, index) => {
         files.append(`file${index}`, allFiles[item])
     })

     product.files = files

     products.push(product)
})
```

Comment: Потестируй свои циклы и посмотри с какими данными ты имеешь дело...

Comment: Конечно же я тестировал свои данные и с ними всё отлично, поэтому дело не в данных которые внутри

Comment: Мы-то твой код как потестим? Пример не полный...

Comment: *"объект formData пустой"* --- каким образом проверяешь этот факт?   ...... *"я тестировал свои данные"*  --- как тестировал этот факт?

Comment: А разве не с blob нужно работать вместо имён файлов? Или я что-то не понимаю?